# unblocking a car with hackrf One and gnu radio companion does not work properly

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I'm new to SDR, I'm trying to perform a replay attack that consists of unlocking a blocked car with hackRF ONE and the software gnu radio companion but the problem is that when I record the unlock signal, then I run the replay attack, it locks the car if it is unlocked and does nothing if it is locked.
 I want to clarify that I used as a frequency of 433 Megahertz. I would have liked to share my flowgraph but my reputation does not allow me. If anyone had a similar problem or know the solution to my problem, please share with me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Probably your key fob is using challenge-response exchange with cryptography. Try to use URH (Universal Radio Hacker) to analyze protocol.

Check this video tutorial playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLlKjreY6G-1EKKBs9sucMdk8PwzcFuIPB&v=kuubkTDAxwA

And this keynote [A Suite for Analyzing and Attacking Stateful Wireless Protocols](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/woot18_slides_pohl.pdf)

And my simple tutorial about replay attack [https://habr.com/ru/434634/](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fhabr.com%2Fru%2Fcompany%2Fneuronspace%2Fblog%2F434634%2F)